# How can I draw the data in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have the [following](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=1426171C6256985C&id=1426171C6256985C!136#!/edit.aspx?cid=1426171C6256985C&resid=1426171C6256985C!308&app=Excel) date in Microsoft Excel.

What I want to do is make the `threshold` as the `x-axis`, and each value corresponding to the threshold (i.e; H1, H2, etc) be on the `y-axis`.

So, for instance, I will be having `0.1` on the `x-axis`, and `8` corresponding values on the `y-axis`.

How can I do that in Microsoft Excel? What chart should I choose? Or, what settings should I perform?

Comment: Your data isn't accessible. Can you try another posting, or provide a brief sample here in your question?

Answer (score 0):

XY Scatter with only Markers *might* suit:

[image: SU608285 example]